# Bounded function such that log f is convex

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R^+*})$ such that $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\log f $ is concave.
prove that there exist $A,B >0$ such that : $$f(x) \leq A \exp(-B|x|)$$ for all $x$.

I managed to prove that $f$ is increasing on $]-\infty, a]$ and decreasing on $[a,+\infty[$ for some real $a$ but I am stuck here, I don't know how to use the fact $f$ integrable.

Comment: any ideas to achieve the problem ?